# Number of ways of distributing indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes with extra givens

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions

What is the number of ways to distribute $m$ indistinguishable balls to $k$ distinguishable boxes given no box can be a unique number of balls?

for example: ($m=19$ and $k=5$)
$$x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_5 = 19 $$
Some of the accepted ways are:

$2 , 2 , 5 , 5 , 5$

$3 , 3 , 3 , 5 , 5$

$8 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 8$

and some of the rejected ways are:

$6 , 6 , 1 , 1 , \mathbf{5}$

$4 , 5 , 7 , 2 , 1$

$1 , 1 , \mathbf{15} , 1 , 1$

Note that the number of zero balls in the boxes is acceptable but does not make a difference! This means that in the same case as before if we assume the number of boxes is 6, the following ways are still acceptable:

$2 , 2 , 5 , 5 , 5 , 0$

$3 , 3 , 0 , 3 , 5 , 5$

$0, 8 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max is surely correct that there is no simple formula, though a summation or double summation is plausible.  Anyway, computation via a recurrence is probably the best.  Define $A(m,k)$ to the number of (ordered) compositions $a_1+\cdots+a_k=m$ with no unique term. Note that 0 can't be unique either in this definition.

Note that if all the zeros are removed, we can subtract 1 from each value to get another solution.  That is (using $i$ for the number of 0s),
$$A(m,k) = A(m-k,k) + \sum_{i=2}^k \binom{k}{i} A(m-k+i,k-i).$$
The boundary conditions are just the obvious, such as $A(m,1)=0$ for all $m$, $A(0,k)=1$ if $k=0$ or $k\ge 2$, etc..

To apply the special rule for 0, just include the $i=1$ term at the first step:

$$\mathrm{answer}(m,k) = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} A(m-k+i,k-i).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  but A(11,5) = ? . I'm a programmer and programmed this problem. for 11 balls and 5 boxes, the answer is: 20

Comment: answer(234,123)=6731563588884512543786979422270240487772121342796088665550328825193311483269434127979997754978197 in less than one second. Seems fast enough.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. You are so smart!

Answer (score 3):

Let's first consider the unrestricted case, and let $f(m,k)$ denote the number of ways to distribute $m$ unlabeled balls into $k$ labeled boxes. Then we have the following generating function:
\begin{split}
\sum_{m,k\geq 0} f(m,k) x^m \frac{y^k}{k!} &= \prod_{i\geq 0} \sum_{j\geq 0} \frac{x^{ij} y^j}{j!} \\
& = \prod_{i\geq 0} \exp( x^i y ) \\
& = \exp(y(1-x)^{-1}),
\end{split}
where $i$ stands for a number of balls in a box and $j$ stands for the number of boxes (and so $ij$ stands for the number of balls in the boxes with $i$ balls each).

It is easy to verify that
$$f(m,k) = k!\cdot[x^my^k] \exp(y(1-x)^{-1}) = [x^m] (1-x)^{-k} = (-1)^m\binom{-k}{m} = \binom{m+k-1}{m}.$$

---

Now, if we restrict the number of boxes with $i>0$ balls to not being $1$, and denote the corresponding number of ways by $g(m,k)$, then along the same lines we have
\begin{split}
\sum_{m,k\geq 0} g(m,k) x^m \frac{y^k}{k!} &= \exp(y) \prod_{i\geq 1} \sum_{j\geq 0\atop j\ne 1} \frac{x^{ij} y^j}{j!} \\
& = \exp(y) \prod_{i\geq 1} \big(\exp( x^i y ) - x^iy\big).
\end{split}
I don't think there is a simple formula for the coefficients of this generating function, although it can be used for efficient computing of $g(m,k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain a little more? For example, what is the answer of $g(7,5)$ ?

Comment: $g(7.5)=10$. Here a sample [PARI/GP code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNibEOwjAMBX_lsdmpESoSYoj8DaztkgVaKUqDo4gh-XsqujDdnS7r3SPpzWOCog0PaoHyMDJ7zNr37oHS0aXG94dQbHvasv7J0grN7Eq1F0UdZd3MKuXLleW33BQinw8IsqDtSILOcEgnsP8CRasmPA==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) implementing this g.f.

Comment: Yes that's right. You are also very smart. I thought about it for days but I could not solve it. thank you.

Comment: Max Alekseyev? Could you express the ratio of restriced case to total case? in fact $\frac {\exp(y) \prod_{i\geq 1} \big(\exp( x^i y ) - x^iy\big) } {\prod_{i\geq 0} \exp( x^i y ) }$

Comment: That's the ratio of generating functions, which is irrelevant to $g(m,k)/f(m,k)$ (if this what you want). Given that $f(m,k)$ has a simple formula, computing the latter ratio reduces to computing $g(m,k)$.

Comment: In fact, I want to find the probability of these conditions to the whole in a simple formula.